# set min date for date input php

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have an input date and I want to set its min value to today's date. I use the following script but it doesn't work.

```
<label>Training Time </label>
<input type='date' class='form-control' name='from' id='from' required>

<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    } 

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    } 

    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    document.getElementById("from").setAttribute("min", today);
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Be more specific.

Comment: it allows to select  previous dates

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: no errors appears but allow me to select any previous date

Comment: If you tag this `php` an mention PHP in the title, then I am wondering why you are trying to do this client-side via JS …?

Comment: so how to do it without js?

Comment: Output a `min` attribute on the element directly, and use PHP’s `date` function to format the current date in the right format ...

Comment: I added :<input type='date' class='form-control' name='from' id='from' min='date('Y-m-d')' required> but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working splution:

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("setTodaysDate")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

```html
<input name="setTodaysDate" type="date">
```

Comment: it allows me to select previous dates

Comment: it is working. Not sure why you feel it is not working.

Comment: `type="date"` only works on Chrome, if your using firefox this will not work.